# Need a workaround for mapping domain to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains), but I can't complete the verification step (#4). My domain provider doesn't allow me to add a DNS record for the type AAAA. I tried contacting my domain provider but they say it's not supported. Is there another work around I could do? Should I try using another cloud hosting service like Azure?

Comment: Move your domain from your current domain provider to Google domains.  That is much easier than switching from GAE to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the features and capabilities that **[Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview)** offers. No need for switching Cloud hosting services.

> **Cloud DNS is a high-performance, resilient, global Domain Name System (DNS) service that publishes your domain names to the global DNS in a cost-effective way.**
>
> **[Migrate to Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating)** an existing DNS domain from another DNS provider.
>
> Then, **[Managing Records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/)** will make it easy for you to add and remove a record. This is done by using a transaction that specifies the operations you want to perform. A transaction supports one or more record changes that are propagated together.

### Update

> I would also check out **[Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/)**, which is a fairly new service (still in Beta) and allows you to register your domain name and works like a charm.